# Unable to hit any attributed routes in new WebApi project - only 404s returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, global-asax, attributerouting

I'm building a new Web API project from scratch and am unable to get any response other than 404 (Not Found).

The routes for each controller and method are declared in attributes.

Here is my Global.asax `Application_Start` method.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    Log.Info("Application_Start...");

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(IoCConfig.Register);

    Collaboral.Common.DB.DatabaseUtil.SetRetryStratPol();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

That code calls the method `IoCConfig.Register`.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.DependencyResolver = new TinyIocWebApiDependencyResolver(RegisterDependencies());
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                               name: "DefaultApi",
                               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                              );

    foreach (var route in config.Routes)
    {
        Log.Info($"{nameof(Register)}: Route = \"{route.RouteTemplate}\"");
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I'm logging the routes in the `config.Routes` collection, and I can see from the log file that this collection contains only the default route which I have manually mapped.

> WebApiApplication      | - Application_Start...|
>   IoCConfig              | - Register: Route = ""|
>   IoCConfig              | - Register: Route = "api/{controller}/{id}"|

And here is an example of how I've used the routing attributes.

```
namespace MyApi.Controllers
{
    [BasicHttpAuthorize(RequireAuthentication = true)]
    [RoutePrefix("v1/projects")]
    public class ProjectsController : ApiController
    {        
        [Route("{projectId:guid}/assocs")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = // ...)]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAssociations(Guid projectId)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

The URL I'm attempting is

```
http://localhost/myapi/v1/projects/bbe89597-28ae-40d5-8071-56dfb222f97b/assocs
```

Some additional points:

- this WebApi project is replacing an older version which has been excluded from the solution. The routes are identical
- the project is hosted as an application in IIS. I'm using the same application as the older API but the application's settings (in IIS) point to the local folder for the newer project

What am I missing?

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit to get the response from WebApi?

Comment: Updated with example URL.

Comment: http://localhost/myapi/api/v1/projects/bbe89597-28ae-40d5-8071-56dfb222f97b/assocs ? you're missing both "api" and "assocs" in your url

Comment: What is your Project Url?

Comment: @FIL - I'm running the application under IIS.

Comment: @awj What about endpoint `.../myapi/api/v1/...`?

Comment: @FIL - No difference. "api" should only be required in the URL if the API project was inside another application in IIS or if "api" had been added to the routing attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using 'myapi' in your endpoint? your endpoint should be like

```
http://localhost/v1/projects/bbe89597-28ae-40d5-8071-56dfb222f97b/assocs
```

You can refer this link for more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Because 'myapi' is the name of the application in IIS.

Comment: what is the binding url in iis?

Comment: "_binding url_"? The virtual path in IIS is _/myapi_.

Comment: have you configured url rewrite module in web config?